# Python file corrupted/wrongly enconded

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I'm a first-year college student facing an issue with Python. I've searched about everything on the Stack Overflow but nothing seems to work (or I don't understand them).

Here's the problem: I was coding a stack composed of three files for a stochastic simulation. Today when I tried to open 2 of them, I got the following error:

[image: Code Error]

After clicking ok this is what I got:

[image: Corrupted file?]

I noticed the encoding was marked as **Latin-1** (sometimes **UTF-8 BOM**) whereas on the working files it's **UTF-8**

At first I thought my USB got corrupted after plugging into a cheap USB Hub but then I tried with backups I had sent to someone and tried on 3 different PCs with the same results.

Comment: Sorry for the typos, I'm so nervous didn't check twice..

Comment: Stop developing with windows, you're making it hard for no reason. But seriously, you have to fix your encoding (all should be utf8 without bom), fix your line endings so they are homogeneous, and make it so that your clickodrome shows `yourfile.py` and `yourfile.pyc` as different, clearly identified files. Fumbling with windows settings left as a chore to the reader.

Comment: That looks... purposefully corrupted, almost. These files you're working with - could you show one that's not broken?

Comment: @spectras thanks for the answer but how do I do that with the file in that shape..

Comment: @obskyr The other one working only has 3 returns..also every other python file seem to work fine, just those on my USB, could it be the USB?

Answer (score 0):

add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your file

it will make whole file be encoded with utf8.

Comment: Did that, encoding did change to UTF-8 but the gibberish remains